# Passing an array where single value is expected?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scipy, regression

I am trying to implement simple optimization problem in Python. I am currently struggling with the following error:

**Value Error**: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

As far as I understand, this means that I am somewhere trying to plug in an array where only single value can be accepted. Nevertheless, I haven't managed to come up with a solution, nor have I discovered where is the problem.

My code follows

```
def validationCurve(X, y, Xval, yval):
    #[lmbda_vec, error_train, error_val] = 
    # VALIDATIONCURVE(X, y, Xval, yval) returns the train and 
    # validation errors (in error_train, error_val) for different
    # values of lmbda. Given the training set (X,y) and validation 
    # set (Xval, yval).

    lmbda_vec = [0, 0.001, 0.003, 0.01, 0.03, 0.1, 0.3, 1];
    m = len(y);
    X = numpy.concatenate((numpy.ones((m,1)), X), axis = 1);
    n = len(Xval);
    Xval = numpy.concatenate((numpy.ones((n,1)), Xval), axis = 1);

    error_train = numpy.zeros((len(lmbda_vec), 1));
    error_val = numpy.zeros((len(lmbda_vec), 1));


    for i in range(0,len(lmbda_vec)):
        lmbda = lmbda_vec[i];
        theta = trainLinearReg(X, y, lmbda);
        error_train[i] = linearRegCostFunction(X, y, theta, lmbda);
        error_val[i] = linearRegCostFunction(Xval, yval, theta, lmbda);
    return lmbda_vec, error_train, error_val


def trainLinearReg(X, y, lmbda):
    #[theta] = TRAINLINEARREG (X, y, lmbda) trains linear 
    # regression usingthe dataset (X, y) and regularization 
    # parameter lmbda. Returns the trained parameters theta.

    alpha = 1 # learning rate
    num_iters = 200 # number of iterations
    initial_theta = (numpy.zeros((len(X[0,:]),1))) #initial guess

    #Create "short hand" for the cost function to be minimized
    costFunction = lambda t: linearRegCostFunction(X, y, t, lmbda);
    #Minimize using Conjugate Gradient
    theta = minimize(costFunction, initial_theta, method = 'Newton-CG',
    jac = True, options = {'maxiter': 200})
    return theta

def linearRegCostFunction(X, y, theta, lmbda):
    # [J, grad] = LINEARREGCOSTFUNCTION(X, y, theta, lmbda)
    # computes the cost of using theta as the parameter for 
    # linear regression to fit the data points in X and y. 
    # Returns the cost in J and the gradient in grad.

    # Initialize some useful values
    m, n = X.shape; # number of training examples
    J = 0;
    grad = numpy.zeros((n ,1))

    J = numpy.dot((y- X @ theta).T, (y-X @ theta)) + 
    lmbda*(theta[1:].T @ theta[1:])
    J = J/m

    grad = (X.T @ (y - X @ theta))/m
    grad [1:] += (lmbda*theta[1:])/m


    grad = grad[:];
    return grad
```

I am trying to obtain an optimal regularization parameter by computing cost function and minimizing with respect to theta.
My input values are:

```
X.shape = (100,25), y.shape = (100,1)
Xval.shape = (55,25), yval.shape = (55,1)
```

Outputted errors are:

```
    --> 129 lmbda_vec , error_train, error_val = validationCurve(Xtrain, ytrain, Xva
    lid, yvalid )
    ---> 33 theta = trainLinearReg(X, y, lmbda);
    ---> 49 theta = minimize(costFunction, initial_theta, 
                    method = 'Newton-CG', jac = True, options = {'maxiter': 200})
```

Later I won't to use the optimized model to predict y on new X.
**Could you please advice me where is the problem in my code?**

Also, if you observe any points for improvement in my code, please let me know. I will be glad to hear and improve.

Thank you!

Comment: the error itself tells you **where** it was thrown, add this to your question

Comment: In my experience this error happens when you are doing a comparison like `if val == arr:` with `arr` a `ndarray` array and `val` being some value. It cannot decide whether the if statement is true or not when the result of the comparison is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Nimitz14 hit the general explanation: you've supplied an array where a scalar is required.  This caused a run-time error.  The problem is how to fix it from here.

First, try slapping your favourite debugger on the problem, so you can stop the program at useful spots and figure out exactly *what* array is causing the problem.  This should help you determine where it originated.

Failing that, place some strategic print statements along the call route, printing each argument just before the function call.  Then examine the signature (call sequence) of each function, and see where you might have given an array in place of a scalar.  I don't see it, but ...

Is it possible that you've somehow redefined **True** as an array?